# Getting a file from WAR file

Tags: java, url, path, classloader, war

I am trying to get a file from my WAR file.

```
URL url2 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/package.xsd");
```

And when I print `getPath()`, this is the output:

`/C:/workspacesFresh2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/GServer/WEB-INF/lib/GLibrary.jar!/package.xsd`

So, it finds the `package.xsd`, but I can't open it with that path.

Any ideas as to how I can access the file?

The error:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/workspacesFresh2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Server/WEB-INF/lib/GLibrary.jar!/package.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.`

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "can't open it " ? any Error ? StackTrace ?

Comment: I have included it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't open it using it's path as it's not a normal file, it's a file inside a jar.

one way to access it is to use input stream

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().
    getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/package.xsd");
```

And them you can read from the input stream

Answer (score 0):

The "path" part of an URL is not necessarily the same as a path in a file system. Indeed, your URL is not a file URL, as it points into a JAR file. You cannot take the path and look it up in the file system.

If you want to access it in your application, you must work with streams.

See also: [URL on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)